# Total Commander - Favorites

Tags: total-commander

How to get some favorite folder list in Total Commander?

I'm switching to Total Commander from FreeCommander and really missing FC panel with favorites.

This is how it looks in FC:

[image]
(In FC you can create favorites which opens defined folder(s) in active or active and inactive panel. It's very handy.)

Answer (score 5):

That's called "**Directory hotlist**" in Total Commander, available through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> or the "star" button within the path bar (above folder listing, below tabs):

[image: Screenshot of Total Commander's main folder view, with the button in question highlighted.]

To have a bookmark which changes both panels at once, open the hotlist "Configure" screen and enter the other panel's path in the "Target path" field.

[image]

(In commander-like file managers, the panel currently in focus is "source" and the opposite panel is "target". Left vs right depends on which panel's hotlist menu you open.)

Besides the hotlist, you can also add entries to the **"Start" menu** (at the top of the window) which go to a specific location instead of launching a program – to do this, enter `cd <path>` as the command to run. As with the hotlist, it's possible to switch both panels at once – this time, the "Start path" field is re-purposed for the target panel location.

[image]

Very similarly, you can also define custom **toolbar buttons** that switch to a specific directory. This is also done by specifying `cd <path>` as the command, and optionally the target panel as "Start path".

[image: Screenshot of the "Change button bar" dialog window]

Comment: And the arrow down button right next to the "star" is the "recent folders", also a handy feature.

Comment: Thanks. But... Is possible to create a hotlist entry for both panels? I mean set directories for both panels in single action.  Something like `Name: Let's watch` = `Left panel: CD C:\Movies`, `Right panel: CD C:\TVShows`

Comment: Yes, if you open the Configure dialog, you can enter the 2nd path in the "Target path" field.

Comment: @user1686 Thanks. Do I understand it right, that toolbar buttons could be placed only in `Button bar` and `Button bar2`?

Comment: Yes, there's only two of them. (But as button definitions are stored in their own files, TotalCmd allows you to have a button that loads a whole new .bar file into the button bar, so it's possible to achieve something like "sub-bars" that way. **And,** I only vaguely remember, it might be possible to have buttons that show custom popup menus like the hotlist...)